# I continue to get a warning of parsers when I run this code in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I am trying to get R to read a txt file

```
  library(readr)
  hotels <- read_csv("C:/Users/illn/Docs/LMU/Programming/hotels.txt", 
            col_types = cols(hotels = col_character(), 
                           names = col_character())
                )
```

```
Warning: The following named parsers don't match the column names: hotels, names
```

Comment: Do you have the column names correct

Comment: please include the output of readLines(n=5) for your file